# How does google prediction API work

Tags: machine-learning, prediction, google-prediction

Can someone predict :) or guess how does the Google Prediction API work under the hood?
I know there are some machine learning techniques:
Decision Trees, Neuron networks, naive Bayesian classification etc.

Which technique do you think Google is using?

Comment: This question has been discussed at stackexchange: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6298/what-is-behind-google-prediction-api

Comment: Thanks Jai, make this an answer and ill mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The single **[answer to the question on Stats SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/10760/5505)** is good, given limited information from Google itself. It concludes with the same thought I had, that Google isn't telling regarding the innards of the Google Prediction API.

There was a **[Reddit discussion](http://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/evdxb/what_are_your_thoughts_on_google_prediction_api/)** about this too. The most helpful response was from  a user who is credible due to his prior work in that field (in my opinion). He wasn't certain what Google Prediction API was using, but had some **[ideas about what it was NOT using](http://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/evdxb/what_are_your_thoughts_on_google_prediction_api/c1bddid)**, based on discussions on the Google Group for the Prediction API:

> the current implementation is not able to deal correctly with non-linear
>   separable data sets (XOR and Circular). That probably means that they
>   are fitting linear models such as regularized logistic regression or
>   SVMs but not neural networks or kernel SVMs. Fitting linear models is
>   very scalable to both wide problems (many features) and long problems
>   (many samples) provided that you use... stochastic gradient descent
>   with truncated gradients to handle sparsity inducing regularizers.

There was a little more, and of course, some other responses. Note that Google Prediction API has since released a new version, but it is not any more obvious (to me) how it works "under the hood".